# Button takes 2 clicks to change background-color when using if/else statement

Tags: javascript, css

So for some time now I have been trying to make multiple divs switch colors on click. Which I did manage to do, but the color only changes every 2 clicks. I feel like that's because the divs I have are used as a hamburger menu icon, so you have to press it once for the dropdown menu to open, and then once again for the dropdown menu to close. What I'm trying to do is make the icon white, once you press the icon the color changes to black, and then once pressed again it goes back to white.

Here is the code for the burger icon:

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-list");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-list li");
  const burgerDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".burger div");
  //Toggle Nav
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
    //Animate links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = "";
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${
          index / 7 + 0.5
        }s`;
      }
    });

    //Burger animation
    burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
    $(".burger").on("click", function() {
      burgerDivs.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.style.backgroundColor === "white") {
          element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        } else {
          element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
navSlide();
```

```css
.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="burger">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet so it reproduces the problem. In general, a test like `element.style.backgroundColor === "white"`  is not adviseable (primarily because setting the background color via CSS will not make the above test true); better use your own variable to keep track of the state.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, the hamburger changes the color on a single click and in clicking again it again changes the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the color using CSS only. You don't have to use the JS for this. As you are already adding the toggle class to the menu( Burger ). Please check the CSS code I add and the code I removed (Js )

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-list");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-list li");
  const burgerDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".burger div");
  //Toggle Nav
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
    //Animate links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = "";
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${
          index / 7 + 0.5
        }s`;
      }
    });

    //Burger animation
    burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
});
};
navSlide();
```

```css
.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: white;
}
.burger.toggle div{
background-color: black;
}

body {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="burger">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ArnesKuduzovic, that's Great, it was a pleasure to solve your problem